# Swift - UIScrollView flashScrollIndicators

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiscrollview, indicator

Is there a way to control the duration for how long a UIScrollView's vertical/horizontal indicator flashes for? I am currently using the below code to make it flash, however, I would like to increase the duration it flashes for:

```
 override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        self.sectionDimensionsAndPropertiesScrollView.flashScrollIndicators()

    }
```